# Directional derivative - vector pointing in direction in which function is neither increasing nor decreasing

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$. Find a vector which points in a direction in which $f$ is neither increasing nor decreasing at the point $(2,-1)$.

Attempt: $\nabla f(x,y)=-2i-4j$. So would this be such a vector? I can find the vector which points in a direction in which $f$ is increasing the most, but no clue how to find one which doesn't increase or decrease...

Comment: Do you recall the formula for the directional derivative?

Answer (score 0):

No. Since, if $v=(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$,$$f'\bigl((2,-1),v\bigr)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+ha,-1+hb)-f(2,-1)}h=-2a-4b,$$take $(a,b)$ such that $-2a-4b=0$. For instance, the direction $(2,-1)$ will do.

Comment: Thanks! So in general, can we say that at some point $(a,b)$ for any multivariable function $f(x,y)$, that such a vector would be $ai+bj$?

Comment: No. That works here but, if, say, $g(x,y)=x^2+y$, then $g'\bigl((2,-1),(a,b)\bigr)=4a+b$. So, in this case, $2i-j$ will *not* be such a vector.